# Angular 6 - creating a (non root) module scoped service

Tags: angular, typescript, web, frontend, angular6

As far as i know until angular 6 , all the @Ngmodule providers where registered on the root injector and were served in the main bundle even if only lazy loaded modules used them.

The only only exception to this was if we wanted to [create a non singleton services in a component level](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectable-ngmodule-or-component).

I want to create a singleton service which will be visible only to a specific module (not to the root module), and as a result of that will not be served in the main eagerly loaded bundle.

In saw that in angular 6 the module will no longer need to refer the service via the "providers" , but rather the service will now refer to the module.

This can be done by the `@Injectable` annotation and the `provideIn` attribute.

I didn't find a good and clear example of how can i add a module name which is not 'root', something like this:

```js
@Injectable({ provideIn: <MyLocalModule>})
export class SimpleServiceForLocalUseOnly { […] }
```

Importing the LazyLoaded module and writing it as "MyLocalModule" in the snippet above is causing a WARNING of Circular dependency.
I can solve this by moving the service to other module, but then i'm losing my initial purpose.

List of searched references:

https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4

https://jaxenter.com/new-angular6-143995.html

https://www.ngdevelop.tech/angular-6-features/

https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/05/04/what-is-new-angular-6/

http://ankitsharmablogs.com/getting-started-with-angular-6-0/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xr5l7lT--YU

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some issues regarding circular dependency if we follow this setup according to the  [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroModule } from './hero.module';
import { HEROES }     from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable({
  // we declare that this service should be created
  // by any injector that includes HeroModule.

  providedIn: HeroModule,
})
export class HeroService {
  getHeroes() { return HEROES; }
}
```

You can either ignore the warnings that the compiler raises due to circular dependency between the Module, Service and Component. Or, fallback to the previous methods used in Angular 5.

Register service as providers in lazy loaded module, note that you should not import lazy loaded modules in your root app module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: LazyComponent }]),
  ],
  declarations: [
    LazyComponent
  ],
  providers: [YourServiceHere]
})
export class LazyLoadedModule { }
```

Comment: When i do it i get:
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
HeroService -> HeroModule -> HeroComponent -> HeroService

Comment: it could be a problem with the Angular library itself, basically cause this setup requires circular imports of service, module and component. If it is just a WARNING and your app is working then I think it is safe to ignore. Or you could just not use the way to set up module-scoped services. Just set up the service in the providers array in your lazy loaded module.

Comment: But my initial purpose was not to include this service in the main bundle, adding it to the modules providers array will end up with this result.

Comment: are you lazy loading your module? From my understanding, services registered in lazy loaded modules are lazily loaded as well.

Comment: Yes, this module is lazy loaded, and services which are registered on the module's "providers" are added to the root injector and not being lazy loaded (check you're main bundle and see).
As far as i understand in angular 6 it was changed (in the 2nd link there is a good cover of this).

Comment: I see. Maybe we'll have to ignore the warnings until the new version solves this issue. Sorry I couldn't help you with it.

Comment: Hello, I've verified myself that the services registered in lazy-loaded modules are not in the main bundle. I'll add the setup in the answer.

Comment: Are you with angular 6? So it means it comes out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

To provide a service in a specific module using the newer syntax you just do something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { YourModule } from "path/to/your.module";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: YourModule
})
export class SomeModuleScopedService {}
```

reference: https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules

Comment: It gives circular dependency warning as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by creating an intermediate module that holds only the service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroServiceModule } from './hero.service.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: HeroServiceModule,
})
export class HeroService {
}
```

You don't need much in that module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ]
})
export class HeroServiceModule {}
```

Then your regular module imports the service module:

```
@NgModule({
...
  imports: [
...
     HeroServiceModule
  ]
})
export class HeroModule {}
```

Then you can lazy-load `HeroModule` as normal. This eliminates all the circular dependencies.